# HTML - Button open link inside form

Tags: html, css

I am creating a login feature but I also need a register button. This register button has to be in the same form as the login feature because I need to display them in block.

I have this

```
<form class="login" onsubmit="return validate();" method="get" action="php/home.php">
    <input class="login-panel credentials" id="username" placeholder="Username" name="username"/>
    <input class="login-panel login-button" id="submit" value="Login" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

for logging in but I also need a register button which redirects the user to another page. But since the form already has an action, how would I add this button:

```
<input class="login-panel login-button" type="submit" value="Register"/>
```

to the form and still be able to redirect the user to another page?

Comment: You could give it a `onclick=myFunction()` javascript and use that to redirect to your registartion page.  Just use a `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`

Answer (score 0):

I would use one action in the form, and then have the logic in the destination page.  For example, with PHP:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=='Login'){
   include("/yourloginscript.php");
} else {
   include("/yourregistrationscript.php");
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

AS i can see from your action field you are using PHP so you could something like this:

1.Add a name attribute to your submit buttons:

```
<input name='login' class="login-panel login-button" id="submit" value="Login" type="submit"  />
<input name='register' class="login-panel login-button" type="submit" value="Register"  />
```

Then adjust your php file so it redirect the user if $_POST['register'] was sent:

```
   //First use filter_input to clean your post
    $post_array = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
    //then check the kind of action your user wants to do 
    if(isset($post_array['register'])){
      //will trigger if the register submit button was used
      //So you can redirect the user using header like so:
      header("location:https://yoursite.com/register.php");
    }elseif(isset($post_array['login'])){
      //will trigger if the login submit button was used
    }
```

By experience, if more than one submit button is used on a single form, only the clicked submit button will be sent in the POST. Therefore you can have multiple submit button and trigger different action for each of them.

Answer (score -3):

You should create a button:

```
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='php/register.php'" value="Register" />
```

Comment: A button element is equivalent to the input element in the OP's posting.  This doesn't address the question.